# Deleting subscriptions from Azure Service Bus Topic through C#

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Is there any way to delete subscriptions from Azure Service Bus Topic, through C# code?
(I know how to delete it only through the Azure portal website)

Answer (score 2):

I found that it can be done with [ServiceBusAdministrationClient.DeleteSubscriptionAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.deletesubscriptionasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-administration-servicebusadministrationclient-deletesubscriptionasync(system-string-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken))

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [ManagementClient.DeleteSubscriptionAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient.deletesubscriptionasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-servicebus-management-managementclient-deletesubscriptionasync(system-string-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken)):

> Parameters
> **topicPath**: String
> The name of the topic relative to the service namespace base address.
> **subscriptionName**: String
> The name of the subscription to delete.

**Sample:**
Topic: lorem
Subscription: ipsum

[image]

```cs
var serviceBusConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sample.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=K34CMjptykdwvAT9t7Frz3DX8OlelvSOBWxZfW8oFZwPg=";
var managementClient = new ManagementClient(serviceBusConnectionString);
await managementClient.DeleteSubscriptionAsync("lorem", "ipsum");
```

[NuGet: Azure Service Bus client library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/)

Comment: You were close Markus! Just that you referred me to ManagementClient, instead of ServiceBusAdministrationClient. But you gave me a direction, so thank you!

Comment: Both options are working. I tested my code on my machine

Comment: Both are correct; ManagementClient belongs to the legacy (deprecated) package.  ServiceBusAdministrationClient is the type for the current generation package.